# Trying to set up Orchard Multi-Tenancy on IIS Server

Tags: iis, orchardcms

I am very new to Orchard, and am having a most difficult time setting up IIS bindings. I am not proficient at IIS, and am new to web development in general.

Say I have domain1.com which is the main Orchard site (landlord). I properly set up domain2.com in the Multi-Tenant module. My DNS records on the server work properly if I have domain1.com and domain2.com as separate sites (i.e., I can type in domain1.com and see the Orchard landlord site, I can type domain2.com and see the default page used by my control panel).

I guess I am just having a hard time binding.  I fiddled around with DNS settings using my servers control panel - no luck. I then tried using IIS to "bind" domain2.com to domain1.com but am pretty sure I have made a mess of it. :)

I've searched around for an answer, but nothing seems to work or otherwise I am unable to fully grasp the concept. The Orchard documentation doesn't really deal with IIS bindings (it deals with using the development machine to host the multi-tenant sites, but I am dealing with a live server - all my "development", such as it is, is done).

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get bindings working for multi-tennancy working you can do one of two things.

**Set a catch all domain binding:**
Create a site in IIS with the binding set to all unassigned IP addresses and no host name. Any domain pointing at the IP of your server will point at this site and Orchard multi-tennancy will decide which of your Orchard sites to point it at. Only one IIS site can have this setting or they will clash.

**Add multiple domain bindings:** In ISS create a site for bound to domain1.com, then under edit site click bindings and add a new binding for domain2.com.

Comment: Thanks! I was so wrapped into the problem, I didn't see the obivous. I was binding that way on the tenant site (binding to landlord site in IIS from tenant site), and didn't think to bind the landlord site in the reverse (binding the tenant site in IIS from landlord site).

Comment: I don't know if you know the answer, but I've now just encountered another problem. If you enter www.tenant.com it works fine in Orchard.  However, Orchard's admin for Tenants only allows input for one site. In the instance where a user just types tenant.com, when I tried binding that in landlord site it takes me to the landlord page, not the tenant. I am thinking that adding a new "tenant" in Orchard Tenants admin will literally create a new site, and not take that alternative to the actual tenant site. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can't think of anything. I'd ask a new question as it is a new question.

Comment: You can supply multiple host names by comma separating them. At least you can in 1.6- I realise this question is now 2 years old!